# Why do some Windows programs show some of my RAW images with a purple tint?

Tags: dslr, raw

Yesterday I got my first DSLR, a Nikon D5300. It works great and I have no complaints, however I'm having a strange issue.

In some programs, like UFRaw, as a desktop image, and in **one** of the Windows Photo Viewers, **some** RAW images have a purple tint.

However, in the other Windows Photo Viewer, Adobe Lightroom, GIMP, paint.net, and Photivo, this purple tint is missing.

Here is an example:

[image]

This is a picture of my laptop screen. The picture in the window is the original image. The picture in the background is the **same** image set as my desktop wallpaper (I understand this isn't something anyone should normally do, but it's just an example.)

I thought originally that there might be something wrong with my camera. However, I downloaded sample NEF files from the internet and they are effected too.

That lead me to think there might be something wrong with my display settings or color profiles. However, I also changed these with no luck.

This occurs in Windows 8.1 and Windows 10, which I updated to this morning.

Any ideas? I've looked all over the internet, and similar reports suggest there's something wrong with the white balance, but since I tried different programs and different RAW files, I can't see how that's the problem.

Comment: There is a known problem with Windows 10 if you have a (physically) small display, but with fairly high pixel density, such as a tablet or mobile phone. Apparently Microsoft are supposedly working on a fix, but as it has been present for some time in earlier versions of Windows, I wouldn't hold my breath on a solution.

Comment: I don't have a small screen, I don't think this is the cause.

Comment: is the purple tint present when you have first imported the image into UFRaw? or only showing once you export to a .TIFF, Jpeg ETC?

Answer (score 2):

The RAW files coming out of different camera models generally have different encodings. The purple tint means that that particular software does not have the necessary decoders for D5300's NEF files. Same happened to me when I was examining D750 sample NEFs.

You can try a raw file from an older camera model to see if the tint disappears.

However, in any case, it's not your hardware's (camera or pc) fault.

Comment: Yesterday I installed this: http://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/products/170/NEF_Codec.html  No change. I'm a noob at this, would installing a codec fix this problem?

Comment: It depends on the viewer software. I don't know how it works with Windows viewers. You can try Picasa Viewer, as it is likely to be more up-to-date. If not, refer to the online community of the viewer you use.

Comment: If I still want to use UFRaw, is there any way I can fix it?

Comment: The problem also occurs in RawTherapee, which was going to be my main RAW editor.

Comment: I got this problem in PhotoDirector 7 with Canon 80D CR2 RAW files. Very annoying to run in to this with paid software. Even if I got it from Humble Bundle for next to nothing. This answer clears this up and I will post in their forums knowing it is their fault.