# Problem with Windows 11' s "Photos" application

Tags: nikon, windows, nikon-d70

As I said I have a problem with the Photos application. My DSLR is Nikon D70. Every time I view my images imported from it they have like a purplish ambient color, it only happens in the Photos app. I didn't changed any settings since I have the laptop... It happens in all formats for ex. i made a photo in .nef, and .jpg also but no difference. This is not a big problem, but I mainly use the Photos app to view my pictures. When I go ahead and try to edit the picture in the same app it looks normally. I also have nothing attached to the camera. I do not know English very well so excuse me if there if something grammatically wrong. [image: Example of purplish image in the "Photos" app]

Comment: Can you post a full .nef somewhere we can access it?

Comment: sure thing @Tetsujin: https://www.transfernow.net/dl/nefpicture

Comment: i did not had a nef of the picture i showed in the post

Comment: That doesn't seem to have the same issue, though - or does it when you view it?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Why do some Windows programs show some of my RAW images with a purple tint?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/65927)

Comment: I got the problem, the Photos app doesn't have the necessary decoders for .NEF files of D70. As said in the https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/65927/why-do-some-windows-programs-show-some-of-my-raw-images-with-a-purple-tint